# facebook shareDialog when app is\isn't installed - weird behavior?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer, facebook-share, publish-actions

I'm using the ShareDialog of Facebook in order to share a printScreen image on facebook within my app.

When Facebook app is installed, it works alright.

When Facebook app **isn't** installed, it doesn't work. I see the "loading" screen and then it's disappeared and nothing happens. 
The share dialog object reaches onError callback with the FacebookException:

```
{FacebookGraphResponseException: (#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions httpResponseCode: 403, facebookErrorCode: 200, facebookErrorType: OAuthException, message: (#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions}
```

So do I really need "publish_actions" permission only for facebook web and not for facebook app? weird..

```
Facebook writes:
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

```
"If the Facebook app is not installed it will automatically fallback to the web-based dialog"

"Now the SDK automatically checks for the native Facebook app. If it isn't installed, the SDK switches people to their default browser and opens the Feed Dialog."
```

my code:

```
mShareDialog = new ShareDialog(mActivity);

    mShareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            if (error != null) {
                showDialog("facebook app isn't installed");
            }
        }
    });

    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {

        // get a screenshot
        Bitmap image = getScreenshot();

        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(image)
                .setCaption(getResources().getString(R.string.shareBodyText))
                .build();

        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();

        mShareDialog.show(content);
    }
```

So why does it work when facebook app is installed without the "publish_actions" and doesn't work when facebook app isn't installed?

Answer (score 1):

It's a requirement of the SharePhotoContent, you must have installed the native faceboook app in order to share photos.

From [Facebook Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

> Photos
>
> People can share photos from your app to Facebook with the Share
> Dialog or with a custom interface.
>
> - The photos must be less than 12MB in size
> - **People need the native Facebook for Android app installed, version 7.0 or higher**